# Avoid logging Memcached requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, memcached

I have a Rails daemon which polls a memcached value every 0.01 sec, and I'd like to prevent these read requests from being logged.  Is there a way to disable the logging of certain reads explicitly, or for the memcached from Rails as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rails.cache.mute { Rails.cache.read(:key) }
```

seems to do the trick.